# Twilio ..gather data in SMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sms, twilio

I have been working on Twilio for a while and very comfortable in gathering input from user during a phone call.

However I am in need of implementing a feature to my application where in a customer can text the invoice Number and get back the status as text.

Here is the sample code for phone call

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="Admin/CheckInvoice">
        <Say>
           Please enter invoice number followed by #
        </Say>
    </Gather>
 </Response>
```

In the above code when the customer calls and enters the Invoice number followed by #, the action method (ASP.NET MVC) CheckInvoice gets triggered.

```
public ActionMethod CheckInvoice(string Digits)
{

}
```

How can I accomplish the same using SMS ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilio passes the parameters included in its webhook call to your URL as form encoded values.  Since it looks like you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can just use Model Binding to grab any of those values.

For an incoming SMS messages, your Action method would look something like this:

```
public ActionResult IncomingSms(string Body) {
    // Body id the name of the parameter that contains the SMS message
}
```

The list of the base set of parameters included in the Twilio Request is here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Hope that helps.